# Own website built - how to provide it in another language?

Tags: javascript, html, web, multilingual

**Situation:** I have developed a website/WebGIS, showing a map and describing some points of interest. The website is based on plain html, css, and JavaScript, so no content-management system or any provider is used. The text on the website is provided in German.

**Goal:** I would like to provide an English version of my website, best, if possible with a toggle button.

**Problem:** I have never done it before and I am not aware which possibilities there are and which practices are commonly used. I already searched on the Internet, but most times the answers are given for a specific website-provider.

**Ideas:** These are some ideas that came to my mind, which could work.

- Copy the whole website code, reset the information in English and save it e.g. as "index.html/en", then use a toggle button to link to the English version. Why I think it would be possible is, that the whole code is below 1.5MB.
- Make a global variable set to german/english and integrate wherever text is used an if-condition, testing which language is selected and then using the specified language. I think this would be much more effort, incorporating all the if-conditions.

What way would you choose or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: If you don't have many views, you can definitively serve english versions of these as separate html files. If you do have a lot of views or languages, save your language strings as 2 JSON documents, and load them dynamically with javaScript. Change of language can be a button with an onClick event loading a separate set of strings and injecting them to your html when the page is rendered.

Comment: how much is "many views"? The site is only interesting for local people and maybe some tourists, so I think I would rather put it in the category "not many views"?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to separate your data and presentation later as a start. Then create a content management system that holds all the strings for your supported languages.

For each page requested you would dynamically create the page using the correct CMS language server side and serve that to your user.

The are many systems out there to do this. You choice would largely depend on what programming language you are most comfortable with.

As well as seeing all the correct visual data remember to set the correct html language attribute as well so the browser knows how to handle your pages.

Another challenge you will face is styling. Each language will require style tweaks to ensure labels and content don't break the layout.

Comment: Why would anybody need a CMS to provide multi language for a simple site or application? That case is valid if these strings need to be editable, but it is definitively possible to serve the strings as a simple JSON file for each language or a separate english version of the html document.

Comment: You would still need to separate out the data and presentation later to use the json file. The CMS part is trivial. Getting the architecture right is more important. Also he asked what way I would choose. I can create a Node.js CMS in 2 minutes with language support so for me I would always add a CMS. It makes it scalable, future proof and easy to add new languages.

Comment: I do agree on the benefits of having a CMS, but we are talking about killing a fly with a bazooka here. Also, we don't know if the user asking the question can implement a node backend on his current server infrastructure, or that his app wouldn't need a huge refactor simply to a achieve this. While your points are valid, I don't find them to be a general solution to this simple problem.

Comment: Fair point. I think the crux lies in not having enough detail. Personally I would never implement multi language without a CMS but that is driven from experience i.e it is the best way I know.

Comment: Yes, I also agree that there is not enough info to give a good answer to this.